# MySQL JOIN on MAX

Tags: mysql

I have two My SQL Tables I am trying to join, they are simplified as:

```
+----------------------------+
| customers                  |
+-------------+-------+------+
| customer_id | first | last |
+-------------+-------+------+
| 0           | John  | Doe  |
+-------------+-------+------+
| 1           | Jane  | Doe  |
+-------------+-------+------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| contact_log                                                       |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
| contact_log_id | customer_id | contact_type | date_time           |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 0              | 0           | email        | 2016-05-17 03:21:45 |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1              | 0           | phone        | 2016-05-17 16:11:35 |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
| ...            | ...         | ...          |                     |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I need a query that will select the customers, and their most recent contact time and type. I've tried this query:

```
SELECT
    `customers`.`customer_id`,
    `customers`.`first`,
    `customers.last`,
    `contact_log`.`contact_type`,
    MAX(`contact_log`.`date_time`)
FROM
    `customers`
JOIN
    `contact_log`
ON
    `customers`.`customer_id` = `contact_log`.`customer_id`
```

This usually sorts the `date_time` incorrectly. Upon researching the issue, there is a bug in some MySQL versions where `MAX` and `MIN` don't work correctly with `DATETIME`. So the workaround is

```
MAX(CAST(`contact_log`.`date_time` AS CHAR))
```

So then I get the customer rows, with the latest `date_time`. However, the `contact_type` does not match the time. In the example data, my result looks like:

```
+-------------+-------+------+--------------+---------------------+
| customer_id | first | last | contact_type | date_time           |
+-------------+-------+------+--------------+---------------------+
| 0           | John  | Doe  | email        | 2016-05-17 16:11:35 |
+-------------+-------+------+--------------+---------------------+
```

The `contact_type` does not match that of the `date_time` from the `contact_log` table. I suspect this has to do with the order the `SELECT`/`JOIN` is happening, and when it is filtered. I have to be careful of sub queries (to avoid n+1) because these are very large tables and will be selecting potentially hundreds of rows from both tables.

What is the proper query to get the `contact_type` and `date_time` to match?

**Update**
When I originally asked this question I did not realize you can't have sub-queries in a view. This needs to be saved as a view. For completeness of this question, how would this be broken into multiple views and joined into one?

Comment: I think you need a `GROUP BY` in there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I've experimented with that. grouping on `contact_type` ends up with duplicate entries (and not necessarily the correct `date_time`). grouping by anything else doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Without views**

A simple solution is to use a subquery to get the contact logs ordered by date, called by a global query to group them by customer_id :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        customers.customer_id,
        customers.first,
        customers.last,
        contact_log.contact_type,
        contact_log.date_time

        FROM customers
            INNER JOIN contact_log ON contact_log.customer_id = customers.customer_id -- or LEFT JOIN - see comment

        ORDER BY contact_log.date_time DESC
) logs GROUP BY logs.customer_id
```

If you have a huge database, you'll have to check if the schema is correctly indexed, cache enabled, etc...

**With views**

The logic is the same. The subquery is replaced by a first views, which is requested by a "global" view to group results. Note that I used GROUP BY and not ORDER BY in the "logs" view.

```
CREATE VIEW logs AS 
    SELECT
        customers.customer_id,
        customers.first,
        customers.last,
        contact_log.contact_type,
        contact_log.date_time

        FROM customers
            LEFT JOIN contact_log ON contact_log.customer_id = customers.customer_id

        GROUP BY
            customers.customer_id,
            contact_log.date_time DESC,
            contact_log.contact_type DESC;

CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT * FROM logs GROUP BY logs.customer_id;

SELECT * FROM testview;
```

Comment: Please note that never-contacted customers will not appear with the query I wrote. If you want them to appear, use a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. They will be resulted with NULLs for contact_type and date_time columns.

Comment: I set this using the LEFT JOIN as I need never contacted people too. Again I had the same problem of the `date_time`/`contact_type` mismatch.

Comment: Please re-check, this is not possible.

Comment: Hmm, tried copy pasting your query this time, and filling in the blanks. That seems to have worked, I'll do more testing, and if it succeeds I'll mark it.

Comment: Updated the question. I did not realize views could not have sub-queries. can everything in parenthesis be saved as a separate view, and then changed to `SELECT * FROM view_name logs GROUP BY logs.customer_id` ?

Comment: I will edit my answer. But keep in mind using views is generally bad for performance. Otherwise, there could be a better solution if you can use triggers and modify a bit the schema. Tell me if you are interested.

Comment: I am aware of the downsides, unfortunately I have to use views as I am inheriting a legacy system that needs bug fixes and such until a complete rework can be accomplished.

Comment: If you could use triggers, you could have a more performant solution, ever using a view to request the data.

Comment: The view method does not return the latest `date_time`/`contact_type` pair, though they do match. Investigating it now.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using `MAX` without `GROUP BY`, so you are getting the max data over all records and not per user.
I'd use an inner query to get only the max dates, and join on it:

```
SELECT
    customers.customer_id,
    customers.first,
    customers.last,
    max_contact_log.contact_type,
    max_contact_log.date_time
FROM
    customers
JOIN
    (select customer_id, contact_type, max(date_time) AS date_time
      FROM contact_log GROUP BY customer_id
    ) as max_contact_log 
ON
    customers.customer_id = max_contact_log.customer_id;
```

Comment: This still results in my same problem of a `date_time`/`contact_type` mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Without subquery, here is a solution used `having` clause:

```
select c.*, cl.contact_type, cl.date_time
from customers c
join contact_log cl
on c.customer_id = cl.customer_id
left join contact_log t
on cl.customer_id = t.customer_id
and cl.date_time <= t.date_time
group by c.customer_id, c.`first`, c.`last`, cl.contact_type, cl.date_time
having count(*) <= 1
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbd63/2)</kbd>